# Implicit `this` type for class methods

Tags: typescript

EDIT: It appears this is a known issue in Typescript. A [solution was once implemented](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/6739) but ultimately pulled because of unresolvable performance problems.

This situation comes up often in our codebase:

```
function consumer<T>(valueProducer: () => T) {
    let value = valueProducer();
    console.log(value);
}

class Foo {
    private _value: number = 100;

    getValue(): number {
        return this._value;
    }

    constructor() {
        // Oops! Inside consumer(), getValue will be called with wrong this
        consumer(this.getValue);
    }
}
```

The solution in Typescript is either this:

```
consumer( () => this.getValue() ); // capture correct this
```

Or this:

```
consumer( this.getValue.bind(this) ); // bind to correct this
```

This problem might be obvious to a Typescript/Javascript programmer, but our team is porting a large body of C# to Typescript, and in C# this is *not* an error (i.e. a passed method in C# is automatically bound to the object instance). So I'd like the type system to catch this error, if possible.

The first, obvious step to explicitly type the `this` used on the callback:

```
function consumer<T>(valueProducer: (this: void) => T) {
    let value = valueProducer();
    console.log(value);
}
```

I would expect that to be enough, but it turns out I also need to explicitly type the `this` parameter on the Foo method:

```
class Foo {
    getValue(this: Foo): number { // I could also have written getValue(this: this)
        return this._value;
    }
```

With these two things in place, I now get exactly the error I want:

```
error TS2345: Argument of type '(this: Foo) => number' is not assignable to parameter of type '(this: void) => number'.
  The 'this' types of each signature are incompatible.
    Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Foo'.
```

However, I don't want to have to add `this: this` to every method in my app. Shouldn't the value of `this` in a method implicitly be that of the enclosing type? Is there another way to achieve this same result without adding all that boilerplate noise to my classes?

([plunker for discussed code](https://plnkr.co/edit/4PZfHi87qXjBkonMYTux?p=info))

Comment: The idiomatic way in JS/TS is as you've mentioned: Provide an already bound function to the callback. It's a tricky business, the context in JS, and you'd do best to avoid it as much as possible.

Comment: Yeah, I know how to pass a callback correctly. I want the type system to let me know if I pass it *incorrectly*, which is what type systems are for, right? It turns out it can do that, but only if I explicitly tell the compiler that `this` inside of a `Foo` method is of type `Foo`, which strikes me as something it should already know. So I'm hoping there's something I'm missing (a compiler flag, maybe?)  More likely, that's just how Typescript works and for good reason, but it never hurts to ask. :)

Comment: anyone knows if there's any news about this issue? i'd find it very convenient if typescript could infer the `this` type if a function is assigned to a different object (that actually does not implement the correct `this`)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [EsLint](https://eslint.org/) with a [plugin](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/tree/master/packages/eslint-plugin) for TypeScript. It has a rule that disallows unbound methods:

```
  211:19  error    Avoid referencing unbound methods which may cause unintentional scoping of `this`  @typescript-eslint/unbound-method
```

Using EsLint is generally a good idea, so this shouldn't be a problem. Note that this rule requires type checking, so you need to extend from all the rulesets in the plugin:

```
{
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
  ]
}
```

You could, of course, enable this rule only, but sticking with recommended configs is a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the `this` argument explicitly to the callback, in the same way that the inbuilt javascript functions like `map` also support an explicit `this`:

```
function consumer<T>(valueProducer: () => T, thisArg: any) {
    let value = valueProducer.apply(thisArg);
    console.log(value);
}

class Foo {
    private _value: number = 100;

    getValue(): number {
        return this._value;
    }

    constructor() {
        consumer(this.getValue, this);
    }
}
```

From my point of view uglier than the arrow function approach, but at least you can't forget to pass it.

Comment: I think it's not the answer because he don't want to pass a function that call "this" for the `consumer(...)` function. If I understand correct, he want a constraint error.

Comment: I know that. Unfortunately I can't give a better one :( I don't think that "method with correctly bound this" or "freestanding function which doesn't require this" is currently expressible with typescript. But if one knows a better answer I would also be interested.

Comment: yes, you sure. I think there is no way to do it either.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution #1. Not that bad if you'd compare it to C#.

```
class Foo {
    private _value: number = 100;

    getValue = () => this._value; // <- do this instead

    constructor() {
        // No problems with "this" now.
        consumer(this.getValue);
    }
}
```

getValue will be treated as a class member and will be assigned with a function which is bound to `this`. Thus, you do not need to catch this error because it's not an error anymore. Here's the code generated by the transpiler for ES5 target:

```
function Foo() {
    // Inserted by the TypeScript transpiler with ES5 target:
    var _this = this;
    this.getValue = function () { return _this._value; };
    ...
    // No problems with "this" now.
    consumer(this.getValue);
}
```

[Check it out](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=function%20consumer%3CT%3E(valueProducer%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20T)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20value%20%3D%20valueProducer()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(value)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Foo%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20private%20_value%3A%20number%20%3D%20100%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20getValue%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20this._value%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Oops!%20Inside%20consumer()%2C%20getValue%20will%20be%20called%20with%20wrong%20this%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20consumer(this.getValue)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D)) online in the TypeScript playground.

It won't solve the problem of finding such places in the code, though. Just will make the refactoring a bit easier.

If you need the methods to be properly reflected in a prototype, here's the solution #2. Not that fancy, but works better with an inheritance.

```
class Foo {
    private _value: number = 100;

    getValue(){ return this._value; }

    constructor() {
        this.getValue = this.getValue.bind(this);

        // No problems with "this" now.
        consumer(this.getValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not a viable solution because it breaks inheritance. Making "getValue" a property rather than method means subclasses that overrides getValue (1) can't call `super.getValue()` and (2) will call the wrong `getValue()` in superclass constructors.

Comment: (2) The right value will be called in a superclass constructor (1) That's right, but this thing alone is a minor issue which doesn't make the solution not viable. In fact, this is a pretty common pattern in ES7.

Comment: Ah, yes, you're right with (2) too. There will be the wrong method called. Well, in situations when it really matters to have it in a prototype chain, it's enough to write "this.f = this.f.bind(this);" instead in the constructor, which is an old way of doing this thing. I wouldn't call this situation frequent, though.

Comment: `I wouldn't call this situation frequent, though`  Accessing superclass methods is not an edge case in our code base. This is not even remotely a viable solution *for us*. YMMV

Comment: Not that big deal. An old good `this.getValue = this.getValue.bind(this);` doesn't look that fancy but should be a pretty viable solution for you, if you're looking for a solution.

Comment: \*lol\* Typescript has a clear syntax for class methods which allows superclass calls and polymorphism in constructors. The *only* problem is that I have to explicitly specify the type of `this` to get the type system to warn me about methods being called with the wrong `this`. Rewriting my 250K+ line codebase to use 1990s-era fake methods by binding closures to public properties is *not* a solution to that problem. If I was going to do that, I could explicitly type the `this` parameter, as I showed in my original post. It sidesteps all the problems with your solution *and* it's less code.

Comment: Typescript has a clear syntax for class methods, but it follows JS semantic when it comes to things like inheritance and classes. That's intentional. It's up to you to decide what to do with your particular code base, but if you really want TS type system to be changed it's more reasonable to open an issue in TypeScript github repo.

Comment: All I can say is that I wouldn't explicitly type `this` in a situation you've found yourself in. I would do one of the things I mentioned _and_ opened a ticket in TS GitHub repo (sounds like a reasonable feature request). But of course, it's your code and your decision.

Comment: I *did* opened a TS ticket, and it turns out this feature was considered but was too expensive to implement (see the edit in the OP).  As for "I would do one of the things I mentioned", I honestly think you don't fully understand the problem or have become too attached to your solution because you authored it, because it's *more* code, requires non-standard class method declarations, changes the class interface or requires overwriting existing method definitions, breaks polymorphism, and doesn't allow calling superclass methods. Why do that, when adding a type annotation fixes the problem?

Comment: "I honestly think you don't fully understand the problem or have become too attached to your solution because you authored it" -- funny :). As I said many times, it's your code and it's your responsibility to decide what to do with it, not mine. I tried to help, but I don't really care _that much_. Feel free to do whatever you wish.

Comment: Also, I believe it should be quite clear that `this.f = this.f.bind(f)` _in a class constructor_ does not break the polymorphism. And yes, I would prefer that to ad-hoc closures with explicit `this` typing for several reasons. "Because I'm authored it" sounds really funny (is it the way how cool kids make technical decisions now?) but no, it is not one of them :). Wishing you the best.

Comment: Because there's not enough space here to explain myself in full, I wrote [this just for you](http://tetzfiles.com/temp/gaperton.html). :)

Comment: 1) You don't have to do duplicate `bind` in `Sub`; the base class is enough (surprise!). 2) It's more efficient than your code because the binding is done once during the object construction. That's, in fact, is a very common coding pattern in JS. 3) I appreciate your energy trying to prove me wrong. Seems like its very important to you :)

Comment: Ah, in case you missed it (I'm afraid you did). One of the problems with an ad-hoc methods wrapping is that it produces different closure object every time. It may cause different problems, like, this thing alone breaks subscribe/unsubscribe API: you can't unsubscribe unless you saved your callback somewhere. You may not encountered that yet, but eventually, you will.

Comment: **It's more efficient** It's nonsensical to say it's more efficient without any knowledge of how many methods are being passed and how often. The goal here is to prevent accidentally passing a method to a callback without binding to the correct this. Your approach *requires* a duplicate closure for every class method, whether it's needed or not. Mine does not. **common coding pattern in JS** Not in Typescript. **produces different closure object every time** Only in contrived example code. **I appreciate your energy trying to prove me wrong** http://xkcd.com/386

Comment: *It's nonsensical to say it's more efficient* - of course, it's not. Moving `this` binding to the constructor will result in a single operation of closure creation per bound method. Ad-hoc `this` binding will clearly be the same or worse. 
*Your approach requires a duplicate closure for every class method* - Nah, just for those which needs to be bound. *Not in Typescript* - typescript is no more than a type system for JS, so this proposition lacks evidence at best. I'd say it's plain wrong. *Only in contrived example code* - ad hoc closures _always_ produce different closures every time.

Comment: *Mine does not* as I said many times, you are free to do whatever you think is right. It' doesn't matter for me what will you do with your code. I don't have any intention to argue *what is better for you*. Just told you what I'd prefer the different way, and explained why.

Comment: **of course, it's not** Of course it is. Here's why you don't understand that: **Nah, just for those which needs to be bound.**

You're fundamentally not understanding the point of this exercise, which is to make it impossible to accidentally pass a class method without binding to the correct `this`. My solution is type annotation. Your solution *requires* that we bind all methods in order to get this protection, because *if you don't bind them all, and you passed one to a callback, Typescript won't warn you.*

Comment: **ad hoc closures always produce different closures every time**

Duh. As I already said, the closure is only "ad hoc" because it's trivial example code. In real code, if we wanted to avoid duplicating the closure, we could, including using your approach on that one specific method. The point is that your solution to the actual problem presented here, which you appear to continually lose sight of, is to preemptively bind every method, just incase it gets passed. My solution is to only bind a method if I need to, but I want Typescript to let me know if I forgot.

Comment: **as I said many times**

So you can stop repeating it. You're here arguing in support of your position exactly as I am. Pretending you don't care is cringe worthy. If you don't care about convincing me that your position makes sense, you can stop posting.

Comment: *My solution is type annotation* - your solution is to garbage type annotation of every single method of a class in a hope that in few cases when it would really matter it will give you an error. I doubt that *any* real TS developer would call it a "solution". Such errors are easy to detect resulting in an exception even in very generic tests. Nobody really cares, sorry.

Comment: Let me confirm one more time that I would never choose to add `this : MyClass` to every class method definition in a hope that it will catch the occasionally lost callback context at compile time, for both aesthetic and practical reasons. I see no way how can I save my face now, so it's you who have to find the way to live with it. :)